# Intel anti-theft service and windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, anti-theft

Can I still upgrade to windows 8 when I have the anti-theft service installed from intel? Or will it lock down the computer?

Answer (score 1):

According to [What is Intel Anti-Theft Service?](http://www.intel.com/support/services/anti-theft-svc/sb/CS-033800.htm)
 it does support Windows 8.

> **Operating System:**
>   Windows 7 (32-bit), Windows 7 (64-bit), Windows 8, 32-bit, Windows 8, 64-bit

**However** according to here: [Operating system and browsers](http://www.intel.com/support/services/anti-theft-svc/sb/CS-033826.htm)

> The Intel® Anti-Theft Service supports Microsoft Windows*7 operating
>   system, and the following browsers...

It only supports windows 7. Note: This article was updated more recently than the first.

This article, updated several months ago seems to indicate it will work:

[Intel® 3rd Generation Core Processors and Windows 8: Better Together](http://communities.intel.com/community/vproexpert/blog/2012/06/19/intel-3rd-generation-core-processors-and-windows-8-better-together)

> Security Enabled: Anti-theft technology (i.e. AT) and Identity Protection Technology (i.e. IPT) are those security features embedded into Ultrabook platform

---

It's probably the case that Intel haven't gotten around to updating all their articles but as they are contradictory your mileage may vary and you may want to get direct confirmation from them, or another user of their product.

Comment: So basically if the service doesn't work it can't signal intel and the computer will lock down after the default 21 days ?

Comment: It looks like that is possible. Like I say, the information is somewhat contradictory.

Comment: @GeorgeBuckett - Except the first article you linked to hasn't been updated in a month.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - I would just flag the article in question, this would allow Intel, to address the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent quite a bit of time on the phone with intel at support. There is actually two different versions of the at service. 1.5 and 2.0. Only the 2.0 version works with windows 8. That's really nice because I just bought a 3 years of service that only works on windows 7. Don't get this service people. If you buy it ask spesifically for windows 8 support.